# Scrollbar Not Appearing When Page is Zoomed in Angular App

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, scroll, overflow

In my Angular app I have a view that shows table data, with a section for pagination below the data. I'm running into an issue where, if I zoom the page, the content increases in size to the point where not all of the content is visible, but a vertical scrollbar does not appear. Also, this is the case even though I have `overflow: auto` in the container in my css. What do I need to adjust in my css to get the scrollbar to appear when needed? To clarify, this problem pertains to Chrome and Safari. In Firefox the scrollbar appears as expected.

Here is my view code:

```
<!-- START TABULAR-CONTAINER -->
<div class="tabular-container">

    <!-- START ACTION-AREA -->
    <div class="action-area">
        ... 
    </div> 
    <!-- END ACTION-AREA -->

    <!-- START TABLE AREA -->
    <table>
    ...
       <div class="table-spacer"></div>
    </table> 
    <!-- END TABLE AREA -->

    <!-- START PAGINATION CONTROLS -->
    <div *ngIf="records?.data" class="pagination">
        <pagination-controls class="paginator" (pageChange)="pageChange($event)" 
                    id="stream"
                    maxSize="12"
                    directionLinks="true"
                    autoHide="true">
        </pagination-controls>
    </div> 
    <!-- END PAGINATION-CONTROLS -->

</div> 
<!-- END TABULAR-CONTAINER -->
```

And here is my relevant LESS/CSS:

```
    .tabular-container {
      padding: 1.25rem;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .table-spacer {
      padding-top: 1.25rem;
    }

   .pagination {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
```

My understanding is that if the containing div, which here is a class called "tabular-container", has `box-sizing` set to `border-box`, and has `overflow:auto`, that this should work. What am I missing here? What can I tweak in the CSS to get the scrollbar to show when the page is zoomed by a user?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm encountering the same issue.